# Using image in div without using <img> tag

Tags: javascript, image, html

I have a html content

> `<div> <img src="xyz.jpg"> </div>`

where an image is fetched from a web service in hex format. I am converting this hex format to jpeg and displaying in a div. But `<img src="">` requires a source folder where the image will be stored. Since the data is coming from web service and is getting converted into jpeg and displayed in div I can't use `<img src=""`> tag. Do you know about other alternative to achieve this?

Comment: use background-image property of css
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp

Comment: Again this requires a source url, that is what I don't want

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme):

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,...">
```

Comment: you are still using the <img> tag, something the OP doesn't want

Answer (score 0):

you could do it with style and backgroundimage, like so:

```
   <div style="background-image:url(xyz.jpg);"></div>
```

Comment: url again checks for source url where the image is actually stored, but I am not storing the image anywhere..dynamically fetching hex format and displaying into UI..